# Can't create schema for a db with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema, users, role

Use `psql -U postgres` to login.

```
postgres=> CREATE DATABASE mydb;
postgres=> \c mydb;

You are now connected to database "mydb" as user "postgres".
```

When create schema, got

```
mydb=> CREATE SCHEMA main;
ERROR:  permission denied for database mydb
```

What will be the possible denied permission that didn't set?

## Edit

When I run `\l`, it showed

```
   Name    |        Owner         | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |               Access privileges
-----------+----------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------
 mydb      | mydb_administrator   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/mydb_administrator                     +
           |                      |          |             |             | mydb_administrator=CTc/mydb_administrator
 postgres  | postgres             | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 ...
```

`\du` got

```
      Role name       |                         Attributes                         |                          Member of
----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 mydb_administrator   |                                                            | {rds_iam}
 mydb_application     | Cannot login                                               | {}
 mydb_user            |                                                            | {rds_iam,mydb_application}
 postgres             | Create role, Create DB                                    +| {rds_superuser}
                      | Password valid until infinity                              |
 ...
```

All the things were executed by `postgres` user.

Comment: There is something weird. First, `postgres` does not seem to be a superuser (unless you changed the prompt). What do you get for `\du`? Then it seems like either the database belongs to someone else (can't be if you created it), or the permissions are hosed. What do you get for `\l`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you. I edited the question and added the results of `\l` and `\du`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the schema as user `mydb_administrator`, it will work.

But you messed up your installation by removing the `SUPERUSER` property from `postgres`. If that was not deliberate and you have no other superuser, you will have to start PostgreSQL in single-user mode to repair that. See the many existing anwers for details about that.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I changed the db's owner to `postgres` by `postgres` user, it works.